# How to deal special character like " Ñ ñ " importing excel file in R?

Tags: r, import, character, rstudio

I have an excel file containing special character **Ñ/ñ**.

Example data on a cell: **Santo Ñino**

when I import that, it became NA.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please checking the encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**excel**

`read_excel()` from the `readxl`-package works for me

screenshot of `test.xlsx`
[image]

```
library( readxl )
read_excel( "./test.xlsx" )

# name  
# <chr> 
# 1 señor 
# 2 mister
```

**csv-file**

[image]

read using your favourite reader

```
x <- data.table::fread( "./temp.csv")
#      name
# 1: seÃ±or
# 2: mister
```

set encoding of relevant columns to UTF-8

```
Encoding(x$name) <- "UTF-8"
#      name
# 1:  señor
# 2: mister
```

Comment: Thank you Wimpel,

How about text file that has a delimited?